# WPF poor perfomance of loading images on WindowsXP

Tags: wpf, performance, bitmapimage

I have some code to load image thumbs and display them in listbox. It works properly on Win7. On Windows XP i takes about seven-ten minutes to load a few big images, while on seven it takes seconds. How can I speed it up?

```
    public static string AddImage(string file)
    {
        string key = "IMG_" + (++_counter).ToString("00000");
        ImageInfo inf = new ImageInfo();
        inf.OriginalPath = file;
        inf.ID = key;
        inf.OriginalPath = file;

        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.BeginInit();
        bi.DecodePixelWidth = THUMB_SIZE;
        bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bi.UriSource = new Uri(file);
        bi.EndInit();
        inf.ThumbBitmap = bi;

        _storedImageInfo.Add(key, inf);

        return key;
    }
```

ImageInfo is my own class containing references to BitmapImages and images' path. I do not think it has major influence on loading times.

Comment: How does it behave without setting the `DecodePixelWidth` property? See for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14680414/1136211).

Comment: You are right, DecodePixeWidth was reason. Now I'm using method described here - http://hintdesk.com/c-wpf-fast-image-resize/ - and its much, much faster.